# How do I replace variables in HTML with an object of variables from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a system for my web page that gets the content of a template found in the HTML and then replaces the appropriate variables with the corresponding values which is stored in an object. The problem is that nothing is being replaced. In this example, I am getting the contents of an RSS file that displays forum posts. I use ajax to get the contents, then iterate through each item. I assign the xml tag values to an object whose keys correspond to the variabls in the HTML template. For every post found, it should replace the HTML variable with the contents of the xml tag.

This is my Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "rsstest.xml",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'xml',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(xml){
            var news = $('#news-results');
            news.empty();
            if($(xml).find('item').length > 0){
                $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
                    var temp_vars = {
                            news_title: $(this).find('title').text(),
                            news_body: $(this).find('description').text(),
                            news_date: $(this).find('pubDate').text(),
                            news_link: $(this).find('link').text()
                    }
                    var template = $('#news-template').contents().clone();
                    for(const variable in temp_vars){
                        template.text().replace("{"+variable+"}", temp_vars[variable])
                    }
                    news.append(template);
                })
            } else {
                news.append($('<p></p>').text('There is no news to display at this time.'));
            }
        }
    })
```

This is my HTML:

```
<h1>Announcements</h1>
<div id="news-results">
</div>
<div id="news-template" style="display: none;">
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body">
            <h3>{news_title}</h3>
            <p>{news_body}</p>
            <div class="media-footer">
                <div class="col-left">
                    <h4>Posted on {news_date}</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-right">
                    <a href="{news_link}" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked to see what's running? For instance, do you ever get to the `var temp_vars = {` line? Any errors?

Comment: I have added console.log(temp_vars[variable]) just inside the for loop and it logs correctly.

Comment: template.text(template.text().replace("{"+variable+"}", temp_vars[variable]))

Comment: @ACD that makes sense! thanks!

Comment: posting it as answer then :) glad to help

Comment: sorry, but i jumped the gun :( None of the tags are appearing in the source code so it's replacing everything inside the media div with the values of the xml tags.

Answer (score 0):

Code below will only replace the text without assigning it.

```
template.html().replace("{"+variable+"}", temp_vars[variable])
```

You have to assign after replacing the text to update the actual value.

```
template.html(template.html().replace("{"+variable+"}", temp_vars[variable]))
```

Comment: You're right, but can you explain a bit, so as to make the answer more useful to others?

Comment: template.text(value) would wipe out the html. Similarly getting the text() would ignore the html

Comment: yeah sorry acd but i jumped the gun. what charlietfl said is happening.

Comment: obviously it will. why not use .html instead of text?

Comment: That would make more sense

Comment: i've tried that but it keeps saying that template.html() is undefined. Maybe because it's a clone?

Comment: @ShoeLace1291  skip the `.contents()` and clone the element itself

Comment: But this includes the news-template div, which I don't want.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 that's fine, you can append `template.html()` into `news`

Comment: but i still get an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined" at that line.

Comment: personally I would use `template.html(function(_,existing){ return existing.replace(..)})`

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 can you `console.log` your `temp_vars`

Comment: I'm trying to get a jsFiddle set up but the ajax won't run. stand by while i figure this out.

Comment: Well, here is the jsFiddle if you can get it to work http://jsfiddle.net/zn4pausx/1/